Citrix workspace desktop (icaclient) for linux cannot add account
My Citrix workspace desktop for Windows works fine.
When I installed the Linux version (Debian), it cannot add account. The error "Http error" was shown.
It is same network, two different PC with  different OS. Any specific configuration required for linux? I followed the installation guideline from Citrix website.
